# Apply the "expand" command to a file in-place like sed -i

Tags: bash, shell

The `expand` command does not have the equivalent of

```
sed -i <file>
```

`expand` actually does have a `-i` option - but it means

> only after blanks

Is there a `sed` - `expand` dynamic duo combination to achieve the same purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GNU utility expand does not provide the 'in place' update that sed does. It's fairly trivial to reproduce the same result, although the command may be slightly longer.

It isn't possible to parse and update a file simultaneously on an arbitrary file system without risking corruption, and for that reason and others sed doesn't actual do it, although it abstracts it from the user. What sed does, and you can reproduce it yourself, is it saves the output of it's operation on the object file in a temp file, then deletes the original copy and renames the temp as the original.

There are any number of ways to do this, here's one - the file named orig.txt is the file being 'expanded':

```
tmp=`mktemp` && expand orig.txt > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" orig.txt
```

If you never use any arguments beyond the file name to expand, a simple function named `expand` could hide the entire temp file to original file swap, and reproduce the `sed` behavior - this implementation would take a single argument of path/filename

```
expand() {
  [[ "$#" -ne "1" ]] && { echo "A single argument must be provided"; exit 1; }
  tmp=`mktemp` && expand "$1" > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "$1"
}
```

With a little modification we can recreate all `expand` functionality by supporting arguments. There is a slight trick in grabbing the last argument so that we know the filename of the object file so we can ultimately overwrite it with the output of `expand`. The last argument is referenced as `${@ -1}`.

```
expand() {
      [[ "$#" -lt "1" ]] && { echo "At least a file name argument must be provided"; exit 1; }
      # Here we capture the last argument which is the object file name
      fname="${@: -1}"
      # The upcoming call to expand passes on all arguments including the file name
      tmp=`mktemp` && expand "$@" > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "$fname"
    }
```

I didn't test this code out, so I apologize if there is a syntax error I didn't catch.

One of these functions, or a version of them, should be placed into `.bashrc` or an equivalent file that is sourced when you create a new shell so that is readily available.

If you want to be able to specify whether or not the file gets updated 'in place' or the update gets sent to stdout, this function template could be modified to do so based on an additional argument (that doesn't get passed on to expand, but changes how we call expand). I'm not sure if you are looking for that, but I think you have all the info you need to do that now  if you are.

Or for more fun, download the GNU coreutils [source code](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/) and the [sed source code](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/sed), check out how sed handles it, and migrate that code into your new improved version of expand. Send that change back to the maintainers and you've possibly simplified this for all future 'expand' users.

Comment: yea, i did something similar to this .. just checking if I were doing too much work.